# Is it possible to conduct a logistic regression with a metric dependent variable?

Tags: regression, logistic, proportion, linear, transform

I have a dependent variable that is a percentage.  I initially wanted to do a linear regression, but then realized that the outcome is not bounded between 0 and 1. My teacher suggested to transform my metric dependent variable into a dichotomous variable in order to do a logistic regression. 
But I can't find any instructions on how to do such a transformation. 
So my question is: Is it possible to transform a dependent variable that is a proportion into a 0/1 variable, and how would you do that?

Comment: You can do logistic regression without needing to transform it. Do a simple google search for binomial regression for proportions

Comment: Where did the percentage come from? Try to get the numerator and denominator used to generate the percentage. If you cannot get them, maybe there is no good statistical method for you, because in statistics 10/100 = 10% and 100/1000 = 10% are different, and if you cannot find    numerator and denominator you need to treat them as the same.

Comment: I already have the percentages. I received the data from a company. The dependent variable is a number between 0 and 1. So I just need a regression were the outcome will be limited between 0 and 1.

Comment: Suppose you have two 10%. Maybe one comes from 10/100 = 10% and another from 100/1000 = 10%. If you do not have numerates and denominators, you cannot tell the difference just based on 10%. But in statistics 10/100 = 10% and 100/1000 = 10% are different.